# How can I properly send email (with error) from catch ()?

Tags: c#

I consume an API and now I want to handle possible errors in `catch` section. What I want to do now is to send email to given user when error is catched. My `Email` method works fine and sends mails properly. `CallAPI` method also works fine but when I add `Email` method to `catch` section then `CallAPI` method get highlighted with info that 'not all code paths return a value'. I can't return anything in `catch` except for sending an email. So how should I properly send email from `catch`?

**CallAPI**

```
private static async Task<T> CallAPI<T>(string endpoint, string accessToken)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        new Uri(ApiUri, endpoint));

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var responseObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream);

        return responseObject;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await Email(e);

    }
}
```

**Email**

```
private static async Task Email(Exception e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        message.From = new MailAddress("mail@mail.com");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("mail@mail.com"));
        message.Subject = "Test test";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = e.ToString();
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Host = "mail.yyy.com";
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your task is not a void type, and it needs to return something, which you are not returning in the catch block after sending the email.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to _send an email_ every time an exception is thrown. I think a better solution is to use a general-purpose logging system (namely `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`) and then have the system send an e-mail (in a background thread) with an aggregate summary of all errors logged in the past hour or so - that way you won't get spammed, and your system performance won't get bogged-down trying to send hundreds of concurrent emails to yourself.

Comment: What should happen to the program's flow after it's sent the email - should the method still return something (as `responseObject` likely won't have a value if there's been an error), or should the error bubble up to the function's caller?  For the former, implement logic to return the appropriate value given you don't have a valid `responseObject` value; for the latter, include `throw` at the end of your catch block to rethrow the exception, having mailed to inform of the issue but not done anything to create a valid response from this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `default(T)` might work for reference types but I don't suggest it for value types.
Say, if `T` is an `int`, `default(T)` results in `0`, which might actually be an acceptable response.
There should be a more explicit way for the caller to distinguish if the call went in error or not.

With a custom object, such as `ResponseBase<T>`, you can easily detect that by a simple `response.IsSuccess` call.

```
public class ResponseBase<T> {
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; } = true;
    public T Output { get; set; }
}

private static async Task<ResponseBase<T>> CallAPI<T>(string endpoint, string accessToken) {
    var result = new ResponseBase<T>(); // Added this
    try {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        new Uri(ApiUri, endpoint));

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var responseObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream);

        result.Output = responseObject; // Added this
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        await Email(e);
        result.IsSuccess = false; // Added this
    }

    return result; // Added this
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I was also wondering about `HttpResponseException` or `HttpError` instead of `Exception`. Would that be a better option here? I handle http errors for the first time so that's why I look for best error handling option.

Comment: No need to do that unless you have different handlers for different exception I pressume. Also, depending on your needs you can extend that custom class to receive, say, a string: ErrorMessage or any other extra stuff. In short, you can play with it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the return result from your catch scope that you might return
generics type from `Task<T>`

One way you can try to return `default(T)`

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    await Email(e);
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Returning `default(T)` is probably not a good idea because it's unclear if `default(T)` _is meaningful or not_ (e.g. `default(SomeEnumType)` usually is very meaningful, while `default(ClassTyp)` is always `null`. Just saying.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more question - what is returned here? What `default` returns?

Comment: `default(T)` returns `null` for object types, `0` for numeric value types, `0001-01-01 00:00:00` for DateTIme, `false` for bools, and null char (`\0`) for chars.  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default

Comment: I though about this too but I don't think it's a good idea. If `T` is a value type, default might be a meaningful/acceptable result and the caller might can't distinguish whether it went in exception or not.